# Primefaces data exporter

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using p:dataExporter to export the data to client machine. It creates a file in given format based on the data from table  mentioned in the tareget method. On export button click file would be exported to client machine.This all goes fine.
Now I want to provide an 'open' button to let open the file with/without downloading the file to client machine. p:dataExporter dont have such property. Does JSF provide such property or any other component recommended?

Here is my code sample,

```
<p:dataExporter type="#{applicationFilterBean.exportFileType}" target=":appForm:appTable"
                            fileName="#{applicationFilterBean.exportFileName}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no it is not possible because content-disposition is hardcode.

for example, look through `org.primefaces.component.export.PDFExporter` source code:

```
protected void writePDFToResponse(ExternalContext externalContext, ByteArrayOutputStream baos, String fileName) throws IOException, DocumentException {     
    externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/pdf");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Expires", "0");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Pragma", "public");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+ fileName + ".pdf");
    externalContext.setResponseContentLength(baos.size());
    externalContext.addResponseCookie(Constants.DOWNLOAD_COOKIE, "true", Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap());
    OutputStream out = externalContext.getResponseOutputStream();
    baos.writeTo(out);
    externalContext.responseFlushBuffer();
}
```

maybe some other library provide this feature, otherwise you should develop your own DataExporter.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestion Michele, I have created my customExport class. The only change needed was to change responseHeader to Content-Disposition-inline,

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename="+ fileName + ".pdf");
```

This is working absolutely fine.